# How to populate Flash charts on load in Apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have two date pickers, a Go button and a Flash-based chart. The series in the chart fetch data from the database based on the dates in the date pickers, which are populated with default dates. When I press the Go button everything works fine: the chart load and show the graphics as expected.

My problem is that I'd like the chart to populate when I load the page, which is not the case. The chart is simply showing a "No data found" message until I press the Go button.

I checked the load order and it's correct - the date pickers are loaded before the chart. Looking at Page Events I can clearly see that this is the case. I also added a simple HTML chart just to see what happens and it is being populated on load, but not the Flash-based ones.

Is there any configuration I'm missing? Is it even possible to populate the chart on load?

I'm using Apex with product build 4.0.2.00.07 on Oracle 11.2.0.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

**For the benefit to anyone who encounters this problem**

Chances are you have only set the default dates as attributes of the start and end date items. This will make the items render on the screen with the default values you specified, but these values are not saved in the session state and therefore are not accessible to the source SQL for the region until the Go button is pressed.

The solution is to create two Before Header computations; one that will set the start date item and one that will set the end date item. This will set the start and end date items in the session state so they're accessible to the region source SQL on load. Make sure that a condition is included in each of the the computations so that they only set if the value of the item is NULL.